# B-Tree for on-disk storage

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Why is a B-Tree the preferred structure for on-disk storage.
What quality makes it preferrable over a binary tree for secondary storage.
Is that specific 'quality' a feature of the alogrithm itself;or the way in which it is implemented?
Any reference or pointer would be much appreciated.

Comment: (1) Binary tree we use as in-memory data-structure, where is B-Tree we uses for storage structure storage/access structure. (2) In Binary tree (or in-memory) data struct we want minimize operation for efficiency purpose whereas in B-tree we wants minimized number of block access. (3) In binary tree we always have two choices either left or right so searching a key done in log`2`(n) whereas in B-Tree we have `m` choices so searching a key takes in log`m`(n) much efficient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disk seeks are expensive. B-Tree structure is designed specifically to avoid disk seeks as much as possible. Therefore B-Tree packs much more keys/pointers into a single node than a binary tree. This property makes the tree very flat. Usually most B-Trees are only 3 or 4 levels deep and the root node can be easily cached. This requires only 2-3 seeks to find anything in the tree. Leaves are also "packed" this way, so iterating a tree (e.g. full scan or range scan) is very efficient, because you read hundreds/thousands data-rows per single block (seek).

In binary tree of the same capacity, you'd have several *tens* of levels and sequential visiting every single value would require at least one seek.

Comment: is there a good reference for b-tree which illustrates this feature of B-tree well(programming language does not matter)

Comment: Please tell me if my understanding is correct - B-Tree is stored on disk. Whenever a new record is added or deleted, B-Tree on the disk is updated. We stored the head or possibly 2 levels in the RAM, thereby reducing the disk accesses. Is that correct?

Comment: @IUnknown — many years late, but here are some resources I've found helpful concerning B-trees: http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/rust-btree-case/ https://opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp/14_2_B_Trees.html